# better way for logging error and send httpresoponsebadrequest in django

Tags: django, django-views

In my Django view I read the input value from request and send bad request for missing data. I am checking for presence of each input items and if an item in not present logging error and sending httpresponsebadrequest. The below code sample shows what I am doing:

```
first_name = request.POST.get('first_name', None)
if not first_name:
    logger.error("first name missing")
    return HttpResponseBadRequest()
last_name = request.POST.get('last_name', None)
if not last_name:
    logger.error("last name missing")
    return HttpResponseBadRequest()
license_number = request.POST.get('license_number', None)
if not license_number:
    logger.error("license number missing")
    return HttpResponseBadRequest()
zip_code = request.POST.get('zip_code', None)
if not zip_code:
    logger.error("zip code missing")
    return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

Is there a better way to code this. Need you suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One pythonic way is creating a dictionary of the errors like following :

```
errors = {'first_name': "first name missing", ... }
```

And get the inputs by cleaning the forms using `form.cleaned_data` and get the correlate errors of the inputs which hasn't a valid value, from errors dictionary.

```
form = Myform(request.POST)

if form.isvalid():
    my_data = form.cleaned_data
    for item, value in my_data.items():
        if not value:
            logger.error(errors.get(item, ''))
```